# AWS cloudfront with server-side encrypted s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

(This is a generalization/variation on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50166557/how-can-a-cloudfront-distribution-an-aws-kms-key-to-get-an-s3-image-encrypted-at#) based on what I've learned in solving this.)

I use AWS Cloudfront with an S3 origin (i.e. to serve S3 objects).

I want to add [server-side encryption](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/serv-side-encryption.html) to my bucket but continue to be able to access the objects via cloudfront.

I am agnostic about the precise SSE strategy used (so long as it is secure).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have latitude over the SSE encryption type, it is possible to add SSE without the use of a lambda.

*The key is to set the encryption type on the bucket to `SSE-S3` (Amazon S3 Key).*

The main steps are:

1. Set the bucket encryption to `SSE-S3` in Properties (tab) ~> Default encryption (panel) ~> Edit (button)
2. Create a cloudfront distribution
3. Link the bucket and cloudfront distribution via an [Origin Access Identity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html)
4. Add a bucket policy that links the Origin Access Identity to the bucket.

Following the article, ["Serving SSE-KMS encrypted content from S3 using CloudFront"](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/serving-sse-kms-encrypted-content-from-s3-using-cloudfront/), here is an alternative CloudFormation stack corresponding to this distribution:

```yaml
Resources:
  S3Bucket:
    Type: "AWS::S3::Bucket"
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Join
        - "-"
        - - !Ref "AWS::StackName"
          - s3bucket
      BucketEncryption:
        ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
          - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
              SSEAlgorithm: AES256

  S3BucketPolicy:
    Type: "AWS::S3::BucketPolicy"
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref S3Bucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action:
              - "s3:GetObject"
            Effect: Allow
            Resource: !Join
              - ""
              - - "arn:aws:s3:::"
                - !Ref S3Bucket
                - /*
            Principal:
              CanonicalUser:
                Fn::GetAtt: [OAI, S3CanonicalUserId]

  OAI:
    Type: "AWS::CloudFront::CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity"
    Properties:
      CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentityConfig:
        Comment: Origin Access Identity for S3

  Cloudfront:
    Type: "AWS::CloudFront::Distribution"
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig:
        Comment: How to serve content encrypted with SSE-S3 from S3 using CloudFront
        Origins:
          - DomainName: !Join
              - .
              - - !Ref S3Bucket
                - s3
                - !Ref "AWS::Region"
                - amazonaws.com
            Id: S3-regional-endpoint
            S3OriginConfig:
              OriginAccessIdentity: !Join
                - /
                - - origin-access-identity
                  - cloudfront
                  - !Ref OAI
        DefaultCacheBehavior:
          TargetOriginId: S3-regional-endpoint
          ForwardedValues:
            QueryString: "false"
          ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https
        Enabled: "true"
```

- Relative to the above-cited article, this requires specifying an Origin Access Identity (`OAI`) as well as a bucket policy (`S3BucketPolicy`) but no KMS resources.
- In CloudFormation and terraform, you can specify encryption type to be `SSE-S3` by specifying `AES256` (see line `SSEAlgorithm: AES256`).

If you are using terraform, there are a few modules (e.g. [here](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/cloudposse/cloudfront-s3-cdn/aws/latest) and [here](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/QuiNovas/cloudfront/aws/latest)) that essentially do the above with some additional goodies.

Comment: Should be the accepted answer! Thanks!

Comment: @NiklasLehnfeld this is very tardy but thanks for the comment/confirmation: sort of bashful about accepting my own answer to my own question :)